# Slug Url turkish character

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I have one question. I am using slug url function for my SEO friendly url but my function not posted turkish character.

```
function url_slug($str)
{   
    $str = mb_strtolower( trim( $str ), 'UTF-8' );
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i',' ', $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

for example when i post this title: `şekerli bir öğütücü çok ışıklı bir bahçe`

Url shows me : `ekerli-bir-t-c-ok-kl-bir-bah-e`

What can i do here? Anyone can help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `u` modifier in your regex to make it work with UTF-8. Change the following line:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i',' ', $str);
```

to this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^alnum:]]/iu', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: @Jilet There should be a change. Please try again.

Comment: yes it is changed but url said like this :

The requested URL `/susa/ÅŸÃ§Ã¶i-Ã¼-Ä±-ÄŸÃ¼ÅŸÃ¼Ä±` was not found on this server.

Comment: @Jilet Are you sure that the encoding of the page is UTF-8?

Comment: yes i am sure my page is :

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @Jilet Here’s a [**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c787281ff392e841237ec3044a8181f1b54c8a6b) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second line to this

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\x{00E7}\x{011F}\x{0131}\x{015F}\x{00F6}\x{00FC}\x{00C7}\x{011E}\x{0130}\x{015E}\x{00D6}\x{00DC}]/u', ' ', $str);
```

As you can see the new expression extends the range for the Turkish characters  below

```
ç \x{00E7}
ğ \x{011F}
ı \x{0131}
ş \x{015F}
ö \x{00F6}
ü \x{00FC}
Ç \x{00C7}
Ğ \x{011E}
İ \x{0130}
Ş \x{015E}
Ö \x{00D6}
Ü \x{00DC}
```

Expected output:

```
sekerli-bir-ögütücü-çok-isikli-bir-bahçe
```